# Change the appearance of an InputRadio in a Blazor page

Tags: c#, radio-button, blazor, blazor-webassembly, appearance

I'm new to Blazor and just trying my first steps in VS2022 with a client-side WA app.

I do not like the appearance of the built-in `<InputRadio>` component. What I want to achieve was a button-styled radio group.

**The question:**
How can I change the appearance of `<InputRadio>` or create something like *radio groups* myself?

I visited the [original source on github (thank you, MicroSoft, for going OS!)](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputRadio.cs) and found, that the appearance seems to be built here:

```
protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
{
    Debug.Assert(Context != null);

    builder.OpenElement(0, "input");
    builder.AddMultipleAttributes(1, AdditionalAttributes);
    builder.AddAttributeIfNotNullOrEmpty(2, "class", AttributeUtilities.CombineClassNames(AdditionalAttributes, Context.FieldClass));
    builder.AddAttribute(3, "type", "radio");
    builder.AddAttribute(4, "name", Context.GroupName);
    builder.AddAttribute(5, "value", BindConverter.FormatValue(Value?.ToString()));
    builder.AddAttribute(6, "checked", Context.CurrentValue?.Equals(Value));
    builder.AddAttribute(7, "onchange", Context.ChangeEventCallback);
    builder.CloseElement();
}
```

My first idea was to inherit from this class and use an own override for `BuildRenderTree()`. But the `InputRadioContext` needed for `Context` is `internal` and this looks like a dead end now.

I tried to use buttons within `<InputRadioGroup>`, but was not able to deal with the events properly.

Comment: This component simply renders an `<input type="radio" ...`. Normal CSS can be applied to modify that. It also applies `AdditionalAttributes` which means any attributes (classes etc) you place on the `InputRadio` component will be transfered to the `input` element. Side note: I use https://source.dot.net/

Comment: @BrianParker Thank you, I'll read into this... I'm very new to Web-UI :-)

Comment: @BrianParker thank you! After some *trial and error* I came up with the solution I posted as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution is rather trivial for experienced web-developers, but Id like to post an answer in order to help noobs like me :-)

Brian Parker's hint pushed me to this solution, which works fine:

```html
<EditForm Model=@someViewModel>
   <InputRadioGroup @bind-Value=@someViewModel.TheInstance_via_Id>
     @foreach (SomeClass e in someList)
     {
       <InputRadio class="btn-check" id=@e.Id Value=@e.Id />
       <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for=@e.Id>@e.Name</label>
     }
   </InputRadioGroup>
</EditForm>
```

Without a `<br/>` tag the buttons appear as *cloud of chips*.

Hint: First I tried to use the object itself in `@bind-Value` but found, that the *magic binding* does not support all types. That's why I added an *Id-based* binding property to the ViewModel like this:

```
    //the actual property returning an object's instance
    public SomeClass TheInstance{ get; set; } = new SomeClass(Guid.NewGuid(), "n.A.");

    //helps to magically bind <InputRadio> via Guid-Property
    public Guid TheInstance_via_Id
    {
        //returns the actual object's id 
        get => TheInstance.Id;
        //re-sets the actual object from a shared context store
        set => TheInstance= BaseDataContext.ListOfInstances[value];
    }
```